# mongodb select either both documents or none

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am in situation where I have to update either two documents or none of them, how is it possible to implement such behavior with mongo?

```
// nodejs mongodb driver
Bus.update({
  "_id": { $in: [ObjectId("abc"), ObjectId("def")] },
  "seats": { $gt: 0 }
}, {
  $inc: { "seats": -1 }
}, { multi: true }, function(error, update) {
  assert(update.result.nModified === 2)
})
```

The problem with code above it will update even if only one bus matched. In my case I try to book ticket for bus in both directions and should fail if at least one of them already fully booked.

Thank you

Comment: I think you will have to do this with two queries, one to check if it is possible and a second to actually do it. The MongoDB philosophy generally doesn't account for actions which examine more than one document at a time.

Comment: I think the common advice is to change the model to work with a single document. Also, did you check "multi-document transactions" tutorial by MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/ ?